# Checking to see if any .txt files exist in a directory using a Perl script

Tags: perl, file

I have a directory, */home/textfile/*.

I want to use a Perl script to check to see if *.txt file exist in this directory or not.  If they do, I want to have it say "Text files exist".  Otherwise, if there are no text files in the directory I want it to say "No text files exist".

The text files could have any name. I just want to check if there is a text file in that directory, */home/textfile*.

Below is the script I am trying to use:

```
$filedir = "/home/textfile/";
chdir($filedir);
if (-e "`ls *.txt`")
{
    print STDOUT "Text file exist"
}
else
{
    print STDOUT "No text file exist"
}
```

How can I fix this script so it will do what I am looking for it to do?

Answer (score 3):

It's simplest to use `glob` to get a list of all files ending with `.txt` in that directory. It avoids shelling out to use `ls`

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = '/home/textfile';
my @files = glob "$dir/*.txt";

print "No " unless @files;
print "Text file exist\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) about the -X file test operators:

> A file test, where X is one of the letters listed below. This unary
> operator takes one argument, either a filename, a filehandle, or a
> dirhandle, and tests the associated file to see if something is true
> about it.

In wrapping the `ls` command in double quotes, you are hoping to test the filenames that are returned by `ls`, but in reality you are testing for the existence of a file named `'ls *.txt'`.

There are a couple of options. You could use `ls` in a separate step to get all of the text file names and then test for the existence of a single one.

```
my @text_files = `ls *.txt`;
chomp(@text_files);

if ( -e $text_files[0] ) {
   ...
}
else {
   ...
}
```

But since `ls` will *only* return existing files, the `-e` check here is not needed at all. You can simply say:

```
my @text_files = `ls *.txt`;
if ( @text_files ) {
    print "Text file exist"
}
else {
    print "No Text file exist"
}
```

I should also note that, since you don't use `$dir` in your `ls` command, you are not actually looking in the `$dir` directory but the current working directory. You would need to add `$dir` to the `ls` command:

```
my @text_files = `ls $dir/*.txt`;
if ( @text_files ) {
    print "Text file exist"
}
else {
    print "No Text file exist"
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) builtin instead of shelling out to `ls` and let Perl manage how to actually read the files. This is generally the more robust and maintainable solution:

```
my @text_files = glob("$dir/*.txt");
if ( @text_files ) {
    print "Text file exist"
}
else {
    print "No Text file exist"
}
```